# What would cause Process.Start to crash the app with a mailto: address?

Tags: c#, wpf, url, mailto, process.start

Not sure why this is, but the following line crashes our WPF app...

```cs
Process.Start("mailto:example@stackoverflow.com");
```

Here's the exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=System.Diagnostics.Process
  StackTrace:
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

*Note: There is no 'InnerException' reported.*

I've confirmed that a mail handler is properly registered by writing this simple HTML file with a `mailto:` hyperlink to test...

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="mailto:example@stackoverflow.com">example@stackoverflow.com</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

You click the link and the mail client opens right up as expected!

Per another post here on the site, I also tried the Blend Interactions method by importing this...

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Then using it like this...

```xml
<Label Content="Send Email">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
      <ei:LaunchUriOrFileAction Path="mailto:example@stackoverflow.com" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Label>
```

but I get the same exception.

So what could be causing this?

Comment: `UseShellExecute` is `false`, _maybe_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try Setting UseShellExecute:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("mailto:example@stackoverflow.com") { UseShellExecute = true });
```

Comment: I saw various solutions to this actually tiny but annoying problem. None of these worked! But this one does! Excellent but...
When I run it as a web based application on server and use these solution I get Win32Exception: Access is denied

Comment: You mean allowing a web api call to invoke a process on server box? Code Access Security?